# VirtualBox and .vdi file screen and mouse errors

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I had a previous virtualbox working with a .vdi image already saved. I tried to open it today, after updating last time, and now my mouse cursor isn't showing, and the size of the screen is incorrect. I've been trying to fix this to no avail, perhaps I am missing something obvious.

NOTE: The image boots to Ubuntu.

NOTE2: Now my mouse is appearing when I see the login screen, but it disappears after I login.

Answer (score 1):

Install Guest Additions. That might help with the driver needs and all. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html  http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I get the following error when i attemp this:
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
Callee: 
IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217471/having-trouble-using-ubuntu-12-04-iso-in-virtual-box is that the same error you get?

Comment: It has to do with unmounting the CD

Comment: Try: Unmount the cdrom manually, delete the mounting directory and then reboot Ubuntu, by doing this, Ubuntu 9.10 can auto detect CD rom and show it as an icon on Desktop.

Comment: Where do i go to do this?

Comment: terminal: call the command "mount" check where your cdrom is mounted, then, do a umount /path/to/cdrom  after that, "rm /path/to/cdrom -r", then reboot the system.